# An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, microsoft-excel, range

Estou tendo dificuldades em conseguir resolver este erro.

O meu objetivo é recolher dados de um ficheiro de Excel armazena-lo em variáveis c#, que por sua vez serão inseridos no SQL Server 2012.

A leitura é feita linha a linha.

**Eis o código onde o erro acontece:**

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook WB = null;
Excel.Worksheet WS = null;
excelApp.Visible = false;


Convert.ToString(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
Response.Write(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);



string excelpath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
Convert.ToString(excelpath);

string workbookPath = excelpath;

WB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);
WS = excelApp.Worksheets.get_Item("" + TextBox2.Text); 


String connectionString =
   "Data Source=localhost;" +
   "Initial Catalog=Teste;" +
   "User id=sa;" +
   "Password=123;";

Excel.Range last = WS.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);
Excel.Range range = WS.get_Range("A1", last);
object ranger = range.Value;
```

**Erro:**

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code asp.net

Comment: Tem mesmo que armazenar tudo em variáveis? https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.outofmemoryexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sim para depois fazer uma query para as introduzir de forma correta na base de dados. mas o problema não reside ai

Comment: por favor preciso mesmo de ajuda

Comment: Quantas linhas estão sendo lidas?

Comment: Perto de 400 linhas e 142 colunas. eu sei que é possível usando estes métodos mas algo esta a correr mal .

Comment: Cria uma tabela similar a planilha no BD, então insere linha a linha para não carregar tudo de uma vez na variável, aplica sua regra de negócio nesta tabela, transporta os dados para as respectivas tabelas e limpa a tabela de manipulação ao fim do processo. Ou solicita um UP de memória no servidor.

Answer (score 0):

OutOfMemoryException não tem como recuperar da forma tradicional, ela é lançada quando sua aplicação fica sem memória suficiente, isso se dá ao fata de se ler 400*142 strings inteiras para a memória, você poderia divir, lê a primeira linha e emite os dados, depois lê a segunda e emite os dados, não leia tudo de uma vez se não vai ficar sem memória mesmo. esse ranger está recebendo o valor da planilha INTEIRA, tenta fazer dois deles cada um para uma seção da planilha,ou talvez três.

Answer (score -1):

Tal como a mensagem de erro indica, o teu sistema ficou sem memória. O teu ficheiro excel possui 400 linhas e 142 colunas o que, pela dimensão, inviabiliza colocar tudo em memória.
Assim, o que te sugiro é que iteres pelo ficheiro, linha a linha, e escreves diretamente na base de dados. Desta forma as tuas variáveis acabam por ser reescritas não consumindo memória.